# (C++17) efficient Text to Text compression for c++ using only standard libraries?

Tags: c++, text, c++17, compression

I want to compress data like this:

```
1 41 26 11 20 35 22 37 4 17 30 10 25 40 16 31 7 34 21 36 3 
1 41 26 11 35 20 31 7 22 37 4 17 30 10 25 40 16 3 36 21 34 
1 17 4 11 26 15 28 13 41 9 20 35 22 37 24 39 7 31 3 19 34 
1 17 4 11 39 22 35 20 9 37 24 41 13 28 15 26 43 19 34 7 31 3 
1 21 32 19 34 14 29 5 25 10 43 26 13 28 41 24 37 9 33 18 42 3 
1 28 13 24 41 26 43 3 42 18 33 9 37 5 29 14 25 10 21 32 19 34
```

Using C++17.
Data only contain 0~9 and space, which is for delimiter.
Range of integer is 1~1036.
Size of the text is about 2MB, and I want to compress this to 500KB or lower.
Badly, I have to use only the standard library, zlib is not an option.
Compression time can be long, but decompressing time, shorter is better.

Currently tried:

1. Transform integers including delimiter(i.e. "1 " to "1", "10 " to "!"...) into 1~2 byte one UTF-8 character.
   Result was 940KB. Not bad but still large :(
2. Huffman compressing, then Base64 encoding.
   Result was 1.1MB except huffman tree. Worse than Transforming :(

Is there any more option I can try?

Comment: Why can't you use zlib? What stops you from copy-pasting their code (and the license, for this to be legal)?

Comment: Why do you need to get it down to a quarter of its original size? What is the original and actual problem that's supposed to solve? What is your actual assignment or exercise? What are its full list of requirements? What is its full list of limitations? What kind of analysis and design have those requirements and limitations lead to?

Comment: Each character has only 11 possibilities (digit or space), so can be encoded into 4 bits (so 16 possibilities). If you group, you might even reduce (11*11(121) -> 7bits (128 possibilities))

Comment: Each number has 1036 possibilities, so a little more than 10 bits (so grouping is also possible, 2 numbers-> a little more than 20 bits, and so on).

Comment: Compressing to get 25% seems not possible (in general case), I got 7/16 for char version or 11/16 (worst case for single-digit number) (best case for 4-digits numbers would be 11/40 anyway).

Comment: my work is making c++ code to solve numberphile's square sum problem, and now I have to deal with 2000 sequences, which include ~5E5 int. I totally forgot about copying code. thanks.
I will try Jarod42's comment, thank you.

Comment: @Azruine If it's [this problem](https://www.numberphile.com/videos/square-sum-problem) (also discussed elsewhere like [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1264240)), why do you need to compress the data? Please tell us the problem the compression itself would solve?

Comment: *efficient Text to Text compression for c++ using only standard libraries?*  The C++ standard library does not provide text-to-text compression.  You'd need to write the compression routines yourself, or use a compression library that provides the routines for you.

Comment: A more representative sample wouldn't hurt -- currently there are also newlines, not just spaces, and even though you say maximum is 1036, I don't see anything higher than 43 -- does that mean that the distribution is skewed? Does order matter? And so on -- you really need to understand the data thoroughly, if you want to develop an effective compression algorithm.

Comment: Why "then Base64 encoding"?

Answer (score -1):

Unless there is some form of redundancy in your data that you're not telling us about, you're not going to get better than about a factor three in compression. Definitely not a factor of four.